# How to search and delete cells containing "Jan-00" in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task that if the header of a column is "Jan-00", the entire column should be deleted. And there are many columns like this in the worksheet. Jan-00 appears because of invalid formula which is automatically filled in when a column is inserted (I can't change the formula but only delete the columns).  A screen shot of the table is attached below.

[image: screenshot of the table]

This is the corrected code:

```
For i = LastColumn to i+1  step -1
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = 0 And IsDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
    Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
    Else
    End If
 Next i
```

I think the problem here is the point out the correct format of Jan-00? Any advise would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i           As Long
    dim k           as long: k = 1
    Dim LastColumn  As Long: LastColumn = 6

    For i = LastColumn To k Step -1

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = 0 And IsDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
        End If

     Next i

End Sub
```

You have error in the way you reference cells. It should not be `Cells.Value(1,i)` but as shown. Furthermore, I have added a check for the format, whether it is date.

Comment: `i = LastColumn To i`? Did you mean that?

Comment: @Bathsheba - its Friday :)

Comment: Looping backward when deleting is *thematic*. Good point, also the fact that other zeros should not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`Jan-00` is most likely some obscure formatting for the value 0.

So (and tidying up some syntax)

```
If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = 0 Then
```

ought to work.

Also, consider running the loop backwards, else you'll miss out consecutive zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But Cells.Value = 0 does not work?

Comment: what doesn't work about it? What is the error you get?

Comment: `ws.Cells.Value(1,i)` is not a valid VBA syntax.

Comment: @Yaolu or `If ws.Cells(1, i).Text = "Jan-00" Then`

Comment: @Bathsheba  your code works very well with reverse loop. All the columns with jan-00 are deleted. However, at the end, it gives me an error code as runtime error '1004' , application defined or object defined error. I couldn't figure it out why and this stops me from continuing doing the next part of the VBA. Any advise?

Comment: @Yaolu: what is the value of `i` when that happens?

Comment: @Bathsheba i=0,   so i changed the loop from i = LastColumn To i Step -1 to i = LastColumn To i+1 Step -1, it worked. Is this correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
For i = 1 To LastColoumn
    If ws.Cells(1, i).Value Like "Jan-00" Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code, `ws.Cells.Value(1, i)` should instead be `ws.Cells(1, i).Value`.

As `Jan-00` is a date, Excel may have a different value stored in the Cell's value. Select the cell and see what is displayed in the Formula Bar:

[image]

You could either change your if statement to the correct value, or you could test `.Text` instead of `.Value`

Once you delete a column, all the columns to the right of that one move over and so with your current loop a column will be skipped for every column that is deleted. To correct this include `i = i - 1` after your delete statement.